# What's wrong with strcmp in this program?

Tags: c, strcmp

When I run the program and answer "yes", it tells me that I am wrong. Does anybody know a way to execute this type of program?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int strcmp(const char *str1,const char *str2 );

// I am trying to make a program that asks the user to input an answer 
int main() 
{
    char answer[20];


    printf("Can birds fly?\n");   
    scanf("%s", &answer[20]);    


    if(strcmp(answer, "yes") == 0)  
    {
        printf("You are right"); 
    }else
    {
        printf("You are worng"); 
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this line:

```
scanf("%s", &answer[20]);
```

to:

```
scanf("%s", answer);
```

You have to pass to `scanf` the address where you want to put the string, with `answer[20]` you pick the value of the 21th character in the string (undefined because the string is 20 characters only) and then take a pointer to it (garbage, you may even get an access violation).

Comment: @user1867232 Since it works, consider accepting as an answer to your question